# I need to change the domain name but keep the analytics

Tags: google, analytics

I need to change a site domain name from mydomain.com to mydomain.org.  Can I keep the existing Google Analytics code and everything will seamlessly flow from the new domain?

Comment: FWIW, because many people here are only interested in status points they often won't answer a newbie because they don't really want to answer the question, they just want those points.  So to start getting answers you need to build your reputation.

Answer (score 2):

If all you are doing is bumping the analytics to a new domain name simply keep the analytics code in the new site and update the URL in analytics.  This has worked in the past for me.

Comment: That has worked for me too.